# Anyone able to help explain why a Syncfusion chart does not show up in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I followed the instructions here:

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/getting-started?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Added this to my page:

```
        <StackLayout x:Name="abc">
            <chart:SfChart>
                <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                    <chart:CategoryAxis>
                    </chart:CategoryAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                    <chart:NumericalAxis>
                    </chart:NumericalAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            </chart:SfChart>
        </StackLayout>
```

added this to the OnAppearing:

```
        SfChart chart = new SfChart();
        //Initializing Primary Axis
        CategoryAxis primaryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;
        //Initializing Secondary Axis
        NumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new NumericalAxis();
        chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;
```

From the instructions on the page this should show a chart but there are no errors and no chart appears.

Comment: did you initialize the renderer?

Answer (score 1):

To use the chart inside an application, each platform application requires some additional configurations.

Have you done the below configurations?

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/getting-started#launching-the-application-on-each-platform-with-chart

Please refer to the demo sample here and compare it with yours for better clarity. 
https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/xamarin.forms-sfchart

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must missed calling the `SfChartRenderer.Init()` method in the `FinishedLaunching`:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.iOS.Renderers.SfChartRenderer.Init();

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

I just wrote a demo and it worked well.

1:Add nuget packages

2:Call the `SfChartRenderer.Init()` method in the `FinishedLaunching`

3:Add your codes in the Project

4:Run and a blank chart appears

Answer (score 0):

Please set HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions for chart as per the below code snippet.

**Code Snippet [XAML]:**

```
  <chart:SfChart
x:Name="Chart"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

<chart:SfChart.BindingContext>
       <local:ViewModel/>
</chart:SfChart.BindingContext>
 …
</chart:SfChart>
```